# Using Numpy/Tensorflow to quickly turning indexes into a mask

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement a stochastic neural network, in which I'm sampling a mask from a softmax distribution from my output layer to obtain samples to train an unsupervised objective function. I want my sampled mask to only be on at the points I sampled. (i.e. if the output is [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.7] and the sampled index is 3, I want my output to be [0, 0, 0, 1]). How would I do it efficiently over a batch?

Here's how I'm currently doing it, it's slow but it works well.:

```
def Stochastic_softmax_selection(M, K, N_rf, N=1000):
    def select(y_dist, G, lossfn, reg=user_constraint):
        # y_dist: shape(Batchsize, M*K)
        
        # initialize an empty mask
        mask = np.zeros((y_dist.shape[0], N, M*K))
        # sample from the distribution
        sam = tf.random.categorical(y_dist[:, :], N) # has shape of (batchsize, N)
        # iterate over a batch
        for batch in range(y_dist.shape[0]):
            # select N sample points
            for n in range(N): 
                mask[batch, n, sam[batch, n]] = 1.0
        mask = tf.constant(mask, dtype=tf.float32)
        return mask
    return select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
input = tf.random.uniform([10, 20])
x = tf.math.argmax(input, -1)
x = tf.one_hot(x, tf.shape(input)[-1])
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much!